Grafana - Combining Azure Data Explorer Datasource with a static source
I'm working on a Grafana panel which uses a Kusto Language Query (KQL) to pull data from an ADX source. One of these data columns has data in numbers (eg. 7000, 7001, 7002, etc.) but I need to display this data as words which are mapped to each number through a static source (could be JSON, XML, even an API, anything) such as
{7000: "Apple", 7001: "Banana", etc.}

to display the data in the column as Apple, Banana, etc. instead of 7000, 7001, etc.
How would I go about doing this?
I didn't try anything since I don't even know where to start off with this or if it's even possible.

If this mapping is static, you can use Value Mappings feature of Grafana
Let's assume you have the following data and would like to see mapped values instead of numbers in column3:

To achieve that, you can add Override for column3 and specify necessary Value mappings for it. Result would be the following:

